# Conserving watchers in angular ? (ng-repeat POV)

Tags: angularjs

I already know the common patterns of how to deal with ng-repeat performance issues(with watchers) , like : `one-time-bind` , `infinite scroll` , `etc`.

But I saw this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33777660/859154) of a guy that suggested  moving to directive.

Ok so I started with the simple approach of plain old approach

[**Approach #1's plunker:**](http://plnkr.co/edit/RVu2Vw6TgvBycZcAUSuB?p=streamer)

100 items with this html :

```
  <div ng-repeat="e in ct.arr">
      <div class='s'> 
        <span >name:{{e.name}} , age:{{e.age}} , height:{{e.height}}</span>
      <hr>
  </div>
```

This will yield `301` watchers, and I can change the `5'th` items when I click a button :

[image]

*So then I thought about moving it to directive (like the guy suggested):*

[**Approaches #2's plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/B0MqYZGESiHrH78dlrD2?p=preview)

Now the HTML is :

```
 <div ng-repeat="e in ct.arr">
     <div class='s'> 
        <span  my-event="e" ></span>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
```

directive :

```
.directive('myEvent', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      event: "=myEvent"
    },
    link: link,
   }

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
     var ev = scope.event;
     element.text('name:'+ev.name +', age:'+ev.age+' , height:'+ev.height)
  }
});
```

Now I'm down to `101` watchers but now the button is not affecting:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. If i'm right , the 100 watchers are because of the direct alias of the isolated scope via the `'='`. But if it's a direct alias to the item , why i'm not seeing the modification after button click?
2. If I *want to see* the modifications , am I stuck with `301` watchers?  is there anything else which I haven't thought of - that can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Alainlb writes, you are computing the content only once at creation time. And of course just like you write in the comment, using the `template :'<span>name:{{event.name}}  ,age:{{event.age}} , height:{{event.height}} </span>'` adds watches (each `{{ ... }}` is a watch behind the scenes).

First solution that comes to mind is use a watch over the directive's item. A deep watch to be specific, so that it can detect changes to the properties of the object, not only changes to the actual object reference:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('event', function(ev) {
        element.text('name:' + ev.name + ', age:' + ev.age + ' , height:' + ev.height);
    }, true);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/marpxMx5qin7mOlFwp3X?p=preview

**Score: 201 watches**

But we can do better; since we are watching manually, the `=` scope binding is now redundant. Oh, and then the `scope: {}` configuration is empty; we can even do without a scope, neither isolated, nor new-prototypically inherited. Let's use `scope: false` (it saves 1 scope object per iteration, a good gain for many iterations).

We now watch directly the expression given in the `my-event` attribute:

```
.directive('myEvent', function() {
    return {
        scope: false,
        link: link,
    };

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
            attrs.myEvent,
            function(ev) {
                element.text('name:' + ev.name + ', age:' + ev.age + ' , height:' + ev.height);
            },
            true
        );
    }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/lvnIQCJMnniFlOeRseaZ?p=preview

**Score: 101 watches**

---

**There is a catch:** Deep watching produces less watches, but they are more expensive because they iterate every property of the watched object. So the real performance gain may be less than what it seems - 101 watches vs 301 watches. Can we do better?

Before even trying, I would first measure the real performance difference between the 101 deep watches and 301 simple watches. If negligible, we are OK. Otherwise we may be able to become "smarter" in our updates using Javascript property getters and setters and maybe manually setting dirty flags on objects. This will be complicated.

A better approach would be to never change the inner properties of an object (treat it as immutable - a good idea in general) and change the reference itself. I.e. do:

```
vm.c10 = function (){
    this.arr[4] = {
        name: "aaaa",
        age: "aaaa",
        height: "aaaa"
    };
};
```

Then you no longer have to deep watch (remove the `, true` from the arguments of `scope.$watch`). This works best if you can enforce the convention that the objects are immutable ([Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) anybody?), you are working alone, or the team (now and in the future) has good communication and understanding of this convention. Expect evil bugs otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you use link, who compile the html of the directive one time and display it

try this http://plnkr.co/edit/spYF935i5TIX9HApVTF4?p=preview

```
.directive('myEvent', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      event: "=myEvent"
    }
    , template :'<span>name:{{event.name}}  ,age:{{event.age}} , height:{{event.height}} </span>'
   }

});
```